# I am adding mtouch arguments as gcc_flags "-framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia" which is giving error

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am adding mtouch arguments as gcc_flags "-framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia" to  avoid errors which are coming when using Emgu.CV.monotouch.dll,But it is giving error as

```
Error MT0008: You should provide one root assembly only, found 2 assemblies: 'gcc_flags', '/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/Scrapboom-Mongo-ProfilePicCropping/ScrapboomPhone/Scrapboom.iPhone/bin/iPhone/Debug/ScrapboomiPhone.exe' (MT0008)
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc_flags` is **not** a valid option (and is being interpreted as your main assembly name). You are missing the `--` prefix to make it a valid option. E.g.

`--gcc_flags="-framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia"`

will work.

Whenever possible try to avoid extra arguments (e.g. in favor of adding this into the binding's `[LinkWith]` attribute).

The main reason is that the *extra arguments* needs to be (manually) copied across your build configurations.